# append single quote(' ') in query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a small problem on mysql query. (Send via node.js)

```
res.send(SELECT `id` FROM table where `id` ='+id)
```

gives the result with id=4

```
select id from table where id=4
```

but i need to insert single quote in query.

Comment: escape the ' by \' replace using reg expression

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you need:

```
res.send("SELECT id FROM table where id ='"+id+"'")
```

Be careful, this exposes you to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info). Read [`node-mysql`'s documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) on how to avoid this security risk.

Answer (score 0):

double quote it:

```
'SELECT id FROM table where id ='''+id+''''
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE column LIKE '%te''st%'
```

will select all rows where column value contains `te'st`

Answer (score 0):

```
res.send("SELECT id FROM table where id ='"+id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id value needs to be quoted:

```
res.send("SELECT id FROM table where id ='"+id + "'")
```

I'm personally suspicious about direct SQL queries coming from Javascript - it normally means your application is vulnerable to naughty people.